# How to set react state value correctly, when the page loads?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question and I leave the CodeSandbox link below. I have 3 checkboxes. I update the `count` value according to the checked status of the checkboxes. 2 of the checkboxes are selected by default. I have a dummyArray and I am sending the `name`, `value`, `isPreselected` values ​​to the checkboxes as props by returning them with map. So when the page loads, my `count` value should be 10, but it is 5. I tried increasing the `count` value with `useEffect` if the checkbox was selected when it was loaded for the first time, but I guess it only adds the value for the first checkbox, not the second one. I also tried to `foreach` the whole array on page load and update the `count` value if the `isPreselected` value is `true`, but still the same result. How can I fix this?

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-liskov-egpq2s

Answer (score 0):

Inside the useEffect callback, you can iterate over the dummyArray and add the value of each checkbox that is preselected to the count.

```
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

const dummyArray = [
  { name: "checkbox 1", value: 5, isPreselected: true },
  { name: "checkbox 2", value: 5, isPreselected: true },
  { name: "checkbox 3", value: 5, isPreselected: false }
];

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialValue = 0;
    const preselectedValues = dummyArray
      .filter((item) => item.isPreselected)
      .map((item) => item.value);
    const total = preselectedValues.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
      initialValue
    );
    setCount(total);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {dummyArray.map((item, index) => (
        <Checkbox
          key={index}
          name={item.name}
          value={item.value}
          isPreselected={item.isPreselected}
          count={count}
          setCount={setCount}
        />
      ))}
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your initial value at setState. Should be 10 but you set to 0 in this case. To count five for each selected box you can do this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(dummyArray.filter(item=>item.isPreselected).length * 5);
```

It will count the boxes checked and multiply by 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? It worked at the code sandbox.